# What are good options to setup a local PHP 5.4.x/MySQL development environment on OSX?

Tags: php, development-environment, lamp

I'm looking for a way to install a good MySQL / Apache / PHP 5.4 local development environment on OSX. XAMPP is still on PHP 5.3 and I know MAMP makes some changes to my system that it doesn't reverse when uninstalled.

Any good standardized options for OSX ?

Comment: You could just install PHP... alternatively, there is [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com), which contains PHP 5.4. I haven't tried it, personally.

Comment: What about `sudo port install php54`? Configure Apache a bit and setup mysql (can be obtained from mysql.org).